# Wanted to Close ActiveMq Connection

Tags: activemq-classic

I need help with the Embedded ActiveMq and Spring Framework.

**Problem is :-**
I am using Embedded ActiveMQ with Spring framework JMS Support.

As part of development I have a component which publish messages to Virtual Topic. And i have another componet which subscribes messages from the topic.

**Now problem here is the application which is subscribing messages is running in cluster environment i.e one master instance and one slave instance. Events which i have published are going to either master instance or slave instance. But i want messages to be subscribed by only master instance. Is there any way i can block slave instance not to subscribe events?**

We have a system property set to differentiate master and slave instance.I have tried add condition by overriding `createConnection` method of `ActiveMqConnectionFactory` class.

```
if(master) {
ActiveMqConnectionFactory.createConnection} 
else 
return null.
```

in this case, `DefaultMessageListener` of Spring framework which we configured to listen events always trying to refresh connection, since i am returning null for slave, it is failing to create connection. the thread is going to infinite loop with 5000MS interval..

Is there any way i can say MessageListener to stop refreshing connection..

Please kindly help me to resolve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

if the cluster is master/slave...then only one should be active at a given time...sounds like you have dual masters from an AMQ client perspective...

regardless, you can always use ActiveMQ security to control access to a given topic/queue based on connection credentials (see http://activemq.apache.org/security.html)